# Can we disable redirects selectively (On specific requests) gatling

Tags: gatling

My Http protocal, where I am setting disableFollowRedirects.  However there is one get call I am making for which I want the execution to follow redirect.  Can we do that ? I tried disableProtocolChecks but it isn't working

```
.baseUrl(brokerHost)
.acceptHeader("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8") // Here are the common headers
.acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
.acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.5")
.upgradeInsecureRequestsHeader("1")
.userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36")
.disableFollowRedirect
```

For this request I want to execution to follow redirects

```
    .exec(http("Post SAML request to IDP")
      .post(/authentication/SSOPOST/")
      .check(status.is(302))
      .check(header("Location").saveAs("redirecturl"))
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not currently (as of gatling 3.4) possible, neither one way (disable globally and re-enable locally) or the other (enable globally and disable locally). There's no control over followRedirect behavior at the request level.

Now, could you please explain why you would be able to do that?

Usually, people want to disable `followRedirect` because they think they should capture the `Location` response header in the redirect response so they can capture data from the landing page url.

This is wrong. Instead, they should let `followRedirect` enabled and use the `currentLocation` and `currentLocationRegex` checks.

Actually, we're considering removing the `disableFollowRedirect` option, unless we really have a compelling reason not to do so.

Comment: Thank you Stephane.   Here is my situation I am testing OIDC authentication with pkce flow.  In my case openid-connect/enpoint url returns 302 and gives me Location /token url where I get the final token.  But to use the /token url I should send a additional formParam ("code_Verifier"), which is generated at the start of the flow.  In general browser is taking care of it may be via JS.  For my perf test I need to send it for final token exchange.

So is there a way to intercept followredirect and pass this additional value.  Sorry I am new to gatling and did not read all the documentation

Comment: I have more than 10 redirects in the whole process, I am fine allowing followRedirect except the one scenario I mentioned above that's the reason I am trying to disableredirect slectively.  -Thanks

Comment: @Praveen As I explained, you're exactly in the use case where people shouldn't be disabling followRedirect in order to parse the Location response header. You should parse the landing page url with currentLocationRegex.

Comment: I will give it a try.  So using currentLocaitonRegex I can pass additional header details before redirect happen. Thanks

Comment: No. currentLocationRegex lets you parse the landing page url instead of trying to parse the Location header that triggered the redirect to this landing page. Your statement "In general browser is taking care of it maybe via JS." is wrong: JS can't see intermediate requests and responses in a redirect chain.

Comment: I've spent hours with no luck.

1.   Redirect URL
location: https://mytime-web.dev.devcontrol.com.au/redirect#state=7ba85ae3-b0e9-4ee2-850c-f032019811d2&session_state=42e99583-0250-4229-81a4-1980503cd72a&code=1f1d93b4-8c6c-4e69-a883-e2a7345b43a8.42e99583-0250-4229-81a4-1980503cd72a.rolf-myaccount
2.  Redirect happens on this url :  https://mytime-web.dev.devcontrol.com.au/redirect  - Response is 304
3. Now I need to initiate token call  :  /protocol/openid-connect/token for token exchange to happen I need to send code as param (Which is in intermediate redirect URL)  -

Comment: So disabling followRedirect is only way that's working for me.  I am not sure from where the browser is getting that code when making token call.  But token call expects this code for token exchange

Comment: Pretty sure the problem is on your side. But i can't help you with that here, this would be consulting.

Comment: As Stephane said disabling redirects selectively is not a feature of gatling.  However I followed what Stephane suggested and allowed redirects that did workout for me in the end.